# Evaluate an integral with parameters

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I already asked this on stack overflow but was redirected here.

I am trying to solve the (highly non-linear) following system of equations :

[image]

with

[image]

and $g_0$, $\Lambda$ are positive constants which i can attribute a numerical value to. $\sinh^{-1}$ is the inverse hyperbolic sine function.

Mathematica gives me no result when I try to use the function Solve. So I thought it would be a good idea to first try to numerically evaluate the integrals $I_n$ in terms of the parameters $\Delta_1$, $\Delta_2$ and $\Delta_3$ before putting it back into the equations.

**My question :** is there any function designed to give a numerical approximation of an integral which depends on some real parameters ? It could be for instance a polynomial on these parameters, or something more complicated...

Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT : Here is the (corrected according to comments) code I've tried to use :

```
f0[d0_?NumericQ, d1_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
ArcSinh[(10*d0)/(d0 + d1*Cos[2*t]^2 + d2*Cos[2*t])], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
f1[d0_?NumericQ, d1_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
Cos[2*t]*ArcSinh[(10*d0)/(d0 + d1*Cos[2*t]^2 + d2*Cos[2*t])], {t, 0,
2*Pi}]
f2[d0_?NumericQ, d1_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
Cos[2*t]^2*ArcSinh[(10*d0)/(d0 + d1*Cos[2*t]^2 + d2*Cos[2*t])], {t, 
0, 2*Pi}]
f3[d0_?NumericQ, d1_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
Cos[2*t]^3 ArcSinh[(10*d0)/(d0 + d1*Cos[2*t]^2 + d2*Cos[2*t])], {t, 
0, 2*Pi}]
f4[d0_?NumericQ, d1_?NumericQ, d2_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
Cos[2*t]^4*ArcSinh[(10*d0)/(d0 + d1*Cos[2*t]^2 + d2*Cos[2*t])], {t, 
0, 2*Pi}]

FindRoot[{d0 == 
d0*f2[d0, d1, d2] + d1*f4[d0, d1, d2] + d2*f3[d0, d1, d2], 
d1 == d0*f0[d0, d1, d2] + d1*f2[d0, d1, d2] + d2*f1[d0, d1, d2], 
d2 == 2*(d0*f1[d0, d1, d2] + d1*f3[d0, d1, d2] + 
d2*f2[d0, d1, d2])}, {{d0, 1.}, {d1, 1.}, {d2, 1.}}]
```

I've tried many different guesses for the initial values but it looks like it is always converging to zero. Any suggestion of a more efficient way to approach the problem would be very appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You will need to use `FindRoot[]` and `NIntegrate[]` for this task; see if you can come up with good initial estimates for your roots.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please show us the code of what you have tried. Showing the nicely formatted equation is helpful but it is beneficial for people who try to answer your question if you also write the code in Mathematica format. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.

Comment: One correction is the spelling of **Nintegrate**. Should use `NIntegrate`. When corrected `FindRoot` yields an answer but I doubt that is is very good. All the numbers are very close to zero.

Comment: I knew it might be something like that.. Thanks ! I'll try to find a correct initial guess for the parameters.

Comment: See Comment section in answer below. Need clarification on the equation.

Comment: One technique that might work would be to create a `Table` of values of $I_n$ for a range of parameters $\Delta_0$, $\Delta_1$, $\Delta_2$.  (This range would perforce have to include the region where you expect the solution to be.)  Then use `Interpolation` to create an approximate interpolated version of $I_n(\Delta_0,\Delta_1,\Delta_2)$.  Mathematica can find roots of expressions that depend on `InterpolatingFunction`s just as it can with any other function.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne see my comment in the awnser below. I'll modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

### Comment

Realize that there is a difference between your original nicely printed equations and the code that you have typed.

The difference is in the numerator of the function to be integrated.

In the nicely typed set of equations you have `Δ` in the numerator where as in the code you have typed you have `Δ0`.

**Original**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Code**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is correct?

### Original Answer

As I interpret the function inside the integral I see

```
fun[n_, Δ_, Δ0_, Δ1_,  Δ2_, θ_] := 
 ArcSinh[Δ/( Δ0 + Δ1 Cos[2 θ]^2 + Δ2 Cos[2 θ] )] Cos[2 θ]^n
```

This function plots nicely when the denominator stays positive

```
Plot[fun[2, 10, 3, 2, 1, θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but has some nasty singularities when we allow the denominator to go negative

```
Plot[fun[2, 10, 1, 2, 3, θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Numerical Integration

Numerical integration works find for the ***nice*** parameters

```
NIntegrate[fun[2, 1, 3, 2, 1, θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}]

(* 0.725971 *)
```

but we get a complaint for the parameters that produce singularities

```
NIntegrate[fun[2, 1, 1, 2, 3, \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* -5.6803 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that nasty behavior. For now I'm mostly concerned with figuring out the right way to implement the system of equations, I've just edited my question to include the code.

Comment: $\Lambda$ is a high-energy cutoff in my equations (which are gap equations for a certain type of unconventional superconductor). Which is why i set $\Lambda \sim 10 \Delta_0$. But now I've realized that it effectively makes $\Lambda$ a variable, and thus makes the problem more complicated than what it should be... I guess that I should first try to find a guess for what order of magnitude I expect for the $\Delta_i$'s then assign an appropriate numerical value to $\Lambda$.